# Set Active Build Configuration in Xcode via User Script

Tags: xcode, build-automation, applescript

How could I set the active build configuration of my current project in xcode with a shortcut? The idea is to have a shortcut to simply change between building for a device and the iphone-simulator. I think this could be easily be done in AppleScript and then integrated into user scripts but since I don't have any knowledge in AppleScript I ask for your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Xcode"
    tell first project
        set allTypes to its build configuration types
        set its active build configuration type to item 1 of allTypes
    end tell
end tell
```